# Call onClick() on button programmatically

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine, onclick

Sound simple but I need some help here

I have a `Button` that I want to trigger using code.

I already have a `onClick()` functionality attached to this button:

[image]

How can I just trigger it programmatically?

Comment: Create a method and call it in your "onButtonClick" handler and also where you want the button to activate via code.

Comment: Hi, when people answer your question, don't say just *"it doesn't work"*. Put some effort into explaining what doesn't work. Add your new code attempt in your question. This will save both your and the person that provided the answer time. Note that [Juan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45418076/3785314) answer came first and there is no reason it shouldn't work or trigger registered functions on the button. You can simply accept it and move on or just modify your question. Happy coding!

Comment: @Programmer You right, I removed this comment and accept the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [`onClick()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html) is a [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html), you should be able to call [`Invoke()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.Invoke.html) like so:

```
button.onClick.Invoke();
```

Comment: @David, you want to trigger it from the code, is that right?

Comment: @David Can you update your question to show some of the code you have? Maybe we can be more useful.

Comment: My bad, this works perfect. It was an inner problem in the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Timer to execute a method after certain time interval. Remember what you do when someone clicks on "on click" is just attaching a handler(method) to event which is raised by onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire the event on your button with SendMessage and Invoke.

```
mybutton.SendMessage("OnClick()");
myButton.onClick.Invoke();
```